# Clear file name when failed to upload

Tags: javascript, angular, ng2-file-upload

I am using `ng2-file-upload` in my `angular 4` application.
I wanted to validate and throw an error when the file of not expected type would be selected, I am able to do that by using `uploader` built-in function `onWhenAddingFileFailed()`.
But File name will remain in the UI despite it failed to upload. 
Please refer the screenshot below. Kindly let me know if there is a fix which can be done in the Angular way without trying to find the DOM element and modify the value.

[image]

Comment: Dude, reset the input to clear the file name ? I had to comment even if I didnt know the answer :D

Comment: Please tell how shall I do that in angular way, if I have list of input files generated dynamically